# Evaluate Formula Gives Wrong Result

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Why would the evaluate formula give the wrong result with the correct values?

In the evaluate formula window of Excel I get the final following steps.

```
370+27.5*(9.5)
370+27.5*9.5
370+261.25
4,725
```

The result should be 631.25; not 4,725 but I cannot figure out why it is adding incorrectly.

This exact same formula works fine in another workbook; this is from a template we use everyday that has never had this issue before.

Excel 2010; windows 7.

This is from a Vlookup+Vlookup*Vlookup which the final steps are all returning correct values.  But the final result is wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing what the actual excel spreadsheet looks like, this will be difficult to answer.  Is it possible the cell is referencing another cell to get 4725?

Comment: replace each vlookup in sequence with its expected value. see if one of the vlookups is "timing out".

Comment: At the time of writing I was on a laptop, I substituted the actual value as a temporary work around.  Back in the office I could not reproduce the problem on another computer.  I'll have to do more digging.