# Excel calculating formula incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Why would excel calculate a formula incorrectly?

**Original Vlookup being incorrectly calculated:**

```
 =VLOOKUP(C1,B25:D28,3,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(C1,B25:D28,2,TRUE)*(C1-VLOOKUP(C1,B25:D28,1,TRUE))
```

**Final Calculation Steps using evaluate formula window.**

- `780+25*(C1-VLOOKUP(C1,B25:D28,1,TRUE))`
- `780+25*(24-VLOOKUP(C1,B25:D28,1,TRUE))`
- `780+25*(24-24)`
- `780+25*(0)`
- `780+25* 0`
- `780+0`
- `6,755.00`

**Excel Answer:** `6,755.00`

**Answer should be:** `780`

**Cell entries as follows:**

C1 = 24 (Sumif of cells referenced on another page)

`B25` - `D28` =

```
0    $35.00      $-   
4    $35.00      $140.00 
12   $30.00      $420.00 
24   $25.00      $780.00
```

**Update:**

I changed one of the Subif reference cells numbers and it immediately changed the answer to the correct one.  Changing the number back kept the accurate result.  What could cause this behavior?

This file was copied then modified and only the copied file had the problem.  Is this some sort of bug?

This is the second time this has happened.  It has happened before on a copied file but I was not able to reproduce the problem at that time.  We usually do not copy this file so the last time before this was many months ago and the issue was not resolved; just worked around.

I cant think of anything else.  Computer even has unbuffered ECC memory.  Excel 2010.

Edit:
I forgot I did ask this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1105759/evaluate-formula-gives-wrong-result) when this originally occured:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I'm with @Scott - this looks like a [insert random reason](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/bofhserver.pl) problem.  I am however curious about '$-   ' in B28.  Is that a minus sign with currency formatting, or is the dollar sign in the cell?  That _may_ have made a difference when the sheet was written.

Comment: @scott This problem just came up again with the parameters in the question.  I merely mentioned it happening in the past to provide some backround.  I will update the questions to make this more clear.

Comment: @mcalex The value of B28 is "0".  B28 is a formatted cell as "accounting" that shows a "$" sign and "-" instead of 0.

Comment: @mcalex Your link did not work for me and searching "insert random reason" did not bring up anything apparently applicable.

Comment: @Damon apologies.  The (facetious) link is to the 'BOFH excuses page' (googling that term may help).  Essentially it's made up reasons (eg 'Solar flares are impacting the PC magnetic field') for IT problems.  The value in that cell being 0 negates thoughts I had about the problem.  I had an idea that Excel was trying to treat it as the start of a formula, but with a 0 in the cell, this isn't the case.

Comment: Just noticed the 'TRUE's in the VLookup call.  Do you not have the exact values in C1?

Comment: @mcalex yes, C1 is an exact value.  In this case 24.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using 'FALSE' as the last argument to the vlookup.  FALSE is used if you know exactly which value you are looking up. True allows the nearest, non-matching answer to be looked up and returned.